# Add specific CSS class to form elements from the address field

Tags: 8, theming

I try to add a custom css class to a form element inside my [address](https://www.drupal.org/project/address) field for e.g the `postal_code` field and another class to the `given_name` and `family_name` field.

I tried it with a `my_theme_theme_suggestions_form_element_alter`. But then I have to extend all the twig files like `form-element--equal-width-column.html.twig`, for just adding the css class.

```
function my_theme_theme_suggestions_form_element_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables, $hook) {

  if (in_array($variables['element']['#attributes']['class']['0'], ['family-name', 'given-name'])) {
    $suggestions[] = $hook . '__equal_width_column';
  }
}
```

Is it possible to just add a css class to specific form-elements div's, so I don't have to extend all those twig files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`hook_form_FORMID_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/8.2.x) in order to add classes to the fields you want to.

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter();
*/
function hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['my_custom_field']['#attributes']['classe'][] = "my-custom-class"
}
```

Comment: ok but how do I find the ID and the right array's? I have to target the property fields of the Address field..

Comment: With `var_dump`, `kint` or any other debug tool I guess

Comment: yes I know. But with e.g. `var_dump` I cannot get into the address field array? In other words I can't find/debug the variables of the properties (company, given_name, family_name etc) inside the address field

Comment: var_dump isn't well designed to dump objects, use `kint` instead. 
I've told you to use `var_dump` on the `$form_id` variable, which is a string

Answer (score 0):

To get form id , create a custom module and in .module write a hook which is given below:

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter();
*/
function custom_form_form_alter(&$form, 
\Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id){
 dd($form);  
}
```

Then you have to go to the particular route for the form. You will find this

[image: Form ID]

Then you can follow **benftwc's** answer:
use the `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` to add css class.